# How do I edit the files installed by NPM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

**Problem** : So I'm using this npm package [react-qr-scanner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-qr-reader) to scan QR codes in my PWA. Now this is a react based package. The react component(just an example) is like:

```
export function QrReader (props) {
    const videoPreviewStyle = {
         width : 300,
        //bunch of other styles
    }
    return (
        <>
          <Section style={ videoPreviewStyle }></Section>
        </>
    );
}
```

Okay so the 'Section' shown above has element-level css styles applied from the videoPreviewStyle object. Now what I wanna do is customize this section. Now the only way I thought is to actually make changes to the npm installed file(in node_modules folder). I tried it, but didn't work(I don't know why, so if you could answer why that'd be awesome). But I also read that whenever I reinstall the package, that would overwrite my changes, obviously(and I don't want that, so that is out of the question). So how exactly would I achieve this? Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Use [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package). See [How to add custom script before build in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66712147/2873538)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wanna do is fork the repo, just like the user above has said. Make the changes to it. And use it. To install just do

**npm install [ github repo link ]**

and there you have it. If you think, your changes could prove beneficial to others, or could significantly change the way the package works, consider creating pull requests. Cheers!

Comment: thanks, the above answer was close to yours. But I wasn't sure how I'd use the package locally.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to extend `react-qr-scanner` you should fork it on github, you could import in locally to test and then publish it if you like, you could use as a private repo too